# Only replace part of regex match

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to match all strings that have the combination _[[ or ]]_

That part I got down: `(_\[\[)|(\]\]_)`
Now comes the part where I need help though, how do I replace only the underscore in these instances?

In other words, the string: `"_[[2, verb//substantiv//adjektiv]]_"` would result in the string: `"[[2, verb//substantiv//adjektiv]]"`

Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: There are *many* dialects of regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ To get effective help, you should mention which language are you using them in. Bash? C? Ruby?

Comment: My apologies. I am using PhP.

Comment: you can do it in the first pattern, by avoiding catch the underscore, give us your used pattern

Comment: It seems to be possible without regexes: just replace `_[[` with `[[` and `]]_` with `]]`.

Comment: I agree Lars, but I am sure there is a way to just replace the underscores, which would save me the need to replace twice, which would look somewhat ugly. =)

Comment: I wrote the pattern in the questio Halayem. pattern: (\_[[)|(]]\_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you can use here is to simply match the entire pattern and replace it with the same pattern without the enclosing underscores (`_`).

[I created the example here btw.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9bfb9f7458ed476bcef359c39a8c4f6a49354c8b)

Example:

```
$str = 'My _[[string to parse]]_ with some _[[examples]]_';
$parsed = preg_replace('/_\[\[([^(\]\]_)]*?)\]\]_/', "[[$1]]", $str);
echo $parsed;
```

Output:

*My [[string to parse]] with some [[examples]]*

Regex explained:

- `_\[\[` the starting point of the sequence you want to capture
- `([^((\]\]_))]*?)` captures the contents of what is between the opening and closing sequence that is **not** the closing sequence itself
- `\]\]_` the closing sequence

By matching the entire pattern and capturing the contents using a capture group you can replace the pattern entirely with a new substring that includes the contents from the matched pattern.

This is done in the second argument to `preg_replace` which is `"[[$1]]"`

`$1` here stands for the captured group and contains its contents, which will be interpolated between two sets of square brackets.

Since the pattern also matches the underscores (`_`) however, these are also removed but simply not replaced by anything in the second argument.

Comment: Works as a charm and came with a beautiful explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could come up with:

```
$regex = '~
              _\[{2}  # look for an underscore and two open square brackets
              ([^]]+) # capture anything that is not a closing bracket
              \]{2}_  # followed by two closing square brackets and an underscore
          ~x';        # free space mode for this explanation
$string = "_[[2, verb//substantiv//adjektiv]]_";

# in the match replace [[(capture Group 1)]]
$new_string = preg_replace($regex, "[[$1]]", $string);
// new_string = [[2, verb//substantiv//adjektiv]]
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fE6lP1/1) as well as [on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/iPLWNS).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

> match all strings that have the combination `_[[` or `]]_`

You can use this regex :

```
^(?=.*_\[\[).+|(?=.*\]\]_).+$

^               // start of the string
(?=.*_\[\[)     // if the string contains _[[
.+              // get the entire string (if the assert is correct)
|               // OR operands (if the assert is not correct, let's check the following)
(?=.*\]\]_)     // if the string contains ]]_
.+              // get the entire string
$               // end of the string
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qE2jG1/1)

Answer (score 0):

*I'm using this pattern just as an example.*
The goal here is to use the capturing parenthesis. If the pattern matches, you will find your captured string in index n°1 in the **matches** array.

Example :

```
    $pattern = '#_(\[\[[0-9]+\]\])_#';
    $result  = preg_match_all($pattern, '_[[22555]]_ BLA BLA _[[999]]_', $matches);

    if (is_int($result) && $result > 0) {
        var_dump($matches[1]);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "[[22555]]"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "[[999]]"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Halayem, but it's not the pattern that I am using. And I don't think I fully follow what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your pattern to capture the brackets `[]` and replacing the matches with what you captured, something like this:

```
$pattern = "/_(\[\[)|(\]\])_/";
$test =  "_[[2, verb//substantiv//adjektiv]]_";
$replace = preg_replace( $pattern ,"$1$2", $test );
echo $replace;
```

Dollar sign `$` allows you to back reference what you captured with the parenthesis. `$1` means the first capture group, in this case `(\[\[)` ,which means the first pair of brackets, `$2` references the second pair of brackets. Because your pattern uses the `|` operator, only one of your capture groups will have a match, the other one will be empty.

Comment: I think you might be on to something, will need to do some research on the "$1$2". It's not something I am familiar with.